# Gazebo version collides between Indigo and Jade

Tags: ros-jade, ros-indigo

[image: Rosanswers logo]

To finish installing `ros-jade-desktop-full` on Trusty, I had to uninstall `Gazebo2` and install `Gazebo5` related packages, which break many Indigo packages that transitively depend on Gazebo2 (via [gazebo_ros](http://wiki.ros.org/gazebo_ros) etc.) I see at least 2 problems here:

- (As of now) there doesn't seem to be `rosdep` keys for `ros-indigo-gazebo5*` packages, which is suggested [here](http://answers.gazebosim.org/question/8598/how-to-install-ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-control-with/). So I'm afraid changing dependencies in the package.xml files for the packages that depend on gazebo is not yet possible (e.g. I get `$ rosdep install --from-paths src --ignore-src -r -y` --> `Cannot locate rosdep definition for [gazebo5_ros_control]`).
- In the first place [Indigo's official hosted Gazebo version is 2.x](http://gazebosim.org/tutorials/?tut=ros_wrapper_versions#Indigo), based on which I bet there are projects that define the system requirement.

Is there any solution to keep me working on both ROS Indigo and Jade on the same OS, using both Gazebo2 and 5?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/208334/gazebo-version-collides-between-indigo-and-jade/) by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) on ROS Answers with karma: 10937 on 2015-05-01

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Martin Günther](https://answers.ros.org/users/22/martin-g%C3%BCnther/) on 2015-05-26**:
Same here. The deb packages `sdformat-sdf` and `libsdformat2`, which Jade depends on, collide with `libsdformat1`, which Indigo depends on.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There is not, we knew going into this that gazebo2 and gazebo5 could not be installed side-by-side and that would mean that ros-indigo-gazebo-ros-pkgs and ros-jade-gazebo-ros-pkgs could not be side-by-side installed. See: https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/rep/pull/89#issuecomment-67402826

---

Originally posted by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) with karma: 17335 on 2015-06-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2